# Solidity weird calldata line of code. bytes calldata signature -> {(signature);}

Tags: solidity

I never saw something like this and I literally don't know how to search for it. Can someone explain me what (signature) does?

```
   function preRelayedCall(
        bytes calldata signature
    )
    {
        (signature);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does nothing. It is there to prevent some tools for complaining about `signature` not being used.

In recent solc versions you could achieve the same by omitting the name of the parameter.

```
function preRelayedCall(bytes calldata) public pure { }
```

Comment: haha, I can't belive it. Thank you